# Beets too big for quality?

Tags: vegetables

I left my beets in the garden too long and they are very large (some 10 - 12 inches in circumference).  Can you recommend a good way to salvage these or should I just "use them as a learning tool"?  They are red and white varieties.

Thanks!

Comment: Why "salvage"? What happens when you try to use them as any other beet?

Comment: Dice and pickle them.

Comment: 10 inch !!! WOW !!!

Answer (score 6):

Just because beets grow big does not mean they can't be good to eat, if mine ever grew that big I'd celebrate! One beet can feed your entire family at that size.

Try roasting one of them until you can stick a prong into it easily, then remove it and let it cool. The skin will just pull off, they you can cut it and try it. If it tastes like a beet should then treat it like any beet. If it is a bit bland then you can still use them, you just may need to add extra flavors.

Comment: Beets + granulated sugar = my heaven :)

Comment: My favorite is to roast them like I said above, then cut them up and mix with a bit of sea salt and sour cream. Yummy!

Comment: Let us know how it comes out @Eileen

Comment: Rene Redzepi had a method for cooking the previous year's carrots by very very slowly sauteeing them whole in a pan with butter for around an hour or more, turning them and basting with butter frequently. This cause the fibres and woody parts to soften and they have an amazing flavour.  I cant see why this wouldn't work for your beets, but perhaps don't leave them whole!

Comment: Another option is to 'salt bake' them. This should not only keep them soft and moist, but also boost the flavour